# AngularJS - Multiple inheritance to call a controller variable from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a sample service:

```
export class ProjectActionService extends ActionService {

  constructor() {
    'ngInject'
    super($state)
  }

  getProjects() {
    // Call API...
  }
}
```

I would like to change the value of a variable (`this.showLoader`) that exists in a controller from the `getProjects ()` method.

Controller:

```
export class ProjectComponent {
  constructor() {
    'ngInject'
  }

  $onInit() {
    this.showLoader = false
  }
}
```

what is the best way to do it, with a multiple inheritance (mixin), a directive ...?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Show/hide a loader?

Comment: @BillP yes but that exists in the "scope" of the `ProjectComponent` controller

Comment: Where exactly do you call getProjects() ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an appropriate way to deal with it. Your service method should only call the api and get the data and not change controller variables. One way to show/hide loader is changing the boolean before calling and change again after getting the response. A sample inside controller after injecting you service:

```
this.showLoader = true;
this.ProjectActionService.getProjects().then(response => {
...
})
.finally(() => this.showLoader = false);
```